# im trying to export a module in nodejs mongodb through ;module.exports = mongoose.model('product',schema);

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to export a module inside a folder product.js using the code:

```
     module.exports = mongoose.model('product',schema);
```

but when i require the product.js in  another directory product-seeder.js  as follows:

```
     var Product=require('../models/product');
     var mongoose=require('mongoose');
     mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/shopping');
```

and run node product-seeder.js it gives me the following error:

```
    Error: Cannot find module '..models/product'
         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
         at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
         at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
         at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
         at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ombasa phillip\shopping- 
         cart\seed\product-seeder.js:4:13)
         at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
         at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
         at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
         at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
         at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
         at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
         at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: can you please share your folder structure for more clarification ? as it says that the path to module is wrong

Comment: whats the filename where you export
module.exports = mongoose.model('product',schema);

Comment: here is the product.js  file                                                                                 
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;
var schema=new Schema({
 imgPath: { type:String,required:true},
 title:{  type:String,required:true},
 description: { type:String,required:true},
 price: { type:Number,required:true}
 
 

}
 );
module.exports = mongoose.model('product',schema);